# Trouble sending TCP message with Socket.io

Tags: javascript, sockets, tcp, socket.io

So I'm attempting to send a TCP message to a device plugged into my computer, with an IP address of `xxx.xxx.1.32` over port `9999` with Socket.io.  The client successfully connects to the TCP server running on the device, but I can't seem to send any actual message to it.  Here is the output I'm getting from the device:

[image]

And my client-side code:

```
<script src = "https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.1.js"></script>
<script>
    var socket = io('http://xxx.xxx.1.32:9999');
    socket.on('connect', function() {
        socket.send('GPIO,00,0');
        socket.emit('GPIO,00,0');

        socket.on('message', function (msg) {
                alert(msg);
        });
    });
</script>
```

It periodically receives the same messages detailed in the first picture (which makes sense since the `Connection:` field is set to keep alive), but it never seems to send the messages, even after first making the connection.  Any ideas as to what is going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Socket.IO doesn't do plain TCP sockets as that is not possible to do in the browser. Instead it uses WebSockets which require a handshake built on top of HTTP (or alternatively some other HTTP-based fallbacks). If you want to talk to your custom device with Socket.IO you'll have to implement their entire protocol by hand.

If you can't or don't want to run node.js on your device, it might be best to forget Socket.IO and just use plain WebSockets. Or even implement a proxy server on a full-fledged computer that can proxy things over plain TCP.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks for your answer.  Do you think this plug-in would work to do this?  https://github.com/kanaka/websockify

Comment: Looks like something that would do the job, assuming you can get it running on your platform.